# Error when consuming an api from a windows service created in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am having problems consuming my application on localhost from the Windows service that I just created because when trying to consume the API I cannot verify the return value when saving it in a Txt file. I have tested the programming with a scheduled task and it works correctly because it returns the values that I expect.

This is the programming file program.cs

```
namespace MyNewService
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new Service1()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the content of the MyNewService.cs file which connects to my tdcon API on a localhost port:

```
namespace MyNewService
{
    public partial class Service1: ServiceBase
    {
        int tiempo = 5;// Settings1.Default.Tiempo;
        public Thread worker = null;
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                AgregaLog("Inicio el servicio", "OnStart");
                ThreadStart star = new ThreadStart(working);
                worker = new Thread(star);
                worker.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AgregaLog("Ocurrio un problema:" + ex.Message, "OnStart");
                throw;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            try
            {
                if (worker != null && worker.IsAlive)
                {
                    worker.Abort();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AgregaLog("Ocurrio un problema:" + ex.Message, "OnStop");
                throw;
            }
        }
        public void working()
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                AgregaLog("Ejecutando linea " + i, "working");
                i++;
                ejecutarWS();
                Thread.Sleep(tiempo * 60 * 100);
            }

        }
        public void ejecutarWS()
        {
            try
            {
                AgregaLog("ejecutar WS", "ejecutarWS");
                var client = new RestClient();
                if (client != null)
                {
                    AgregaLog("RestClient fallo", "ejecutarWS");
                }
                var request = new RestRequest("http://localhost:7113/Home/SincronizarDatos");
                request.Method = Method.Post;
                if (request != null)
                {
                    AgregaLog("request fallo", "ejecutarWS");
                }
                var response = client.Execute(request);
                if (response != null)
                {
                    AgregaLog("response fallo", "ejecutarWS");
                }
                
                AgregaLog("resultado" + response.Content.ToString(), "ejecutarWS");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AgregaLog("Ocurrio el problema:" + ex+"\n", "OnStop");
                throw;
            }

        }

        public void AgregaLog(string Valor, string Metodo)
        {
            StreamWriter log;
            FileStream fileStream = null;
            DirectoryInfo logDirInfo = null;
            FileInfo logFileInfo;

            string logFilePath = "C:\\Logs_Servicio_TankFarm_Users\\";
            try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(logFilePath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(logFilePath);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // handle them here
            }
            logFilePath = logFilePath + "Log-" + System.DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "." + "txt";
            logFileInfo = new FileInfo(logFilePath);
            logDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(logFileInfo.DirectoryName);
            if (!logDirInfo.Exists) logDirInfo.Create();
            if (!logFileInfo.Exists)
            {
                fileStream = logFileInfo.Create();
            }
            else
            {
                fileStream = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Append);
            }
            log = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
            log.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Today.ToString("[dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm]") + "-" + "METODO: " + Metodo + "-- Desc: " + Valor);
            log.Close();
        }        
    }
}
```

The connection with the API is made in the following lines of code:

```
                var client = new RestClient();
                if (client != null)
                {
                    AgregaLog("RestClient fallo", "ejecutarWS");
                }
                var request = new RestRequest("http://localhost:7113/Home/SincronizarDatos");
                request.Method = Method.Post;
                if (request != null)
                {
                    AgregaLog("request fallo", "ejecutarWS");
                }
                var response = client.Execute(request);
```

When printing what happens in the process in a txt file, it shows me the following:

```
[17-04-2023 00:00]-METODO: OnStart-- Desc: Inicio el servicio
[17-04-2023 00:00]-METODO: working-- Desc: Ejecutando linea 0
[17-04-2023 00:00]-METODO: ejecutarWS-- Desc: ejecutar WS
[17-04-2023 00:00]-METODO: ejecutarWS-- Desc: RestClient fallo
[17-04-2023 00:00]-METODO: ejecutarWS-- Desc: request fallo
[17-04-2023 00:00]-METODO: ejecutarWS-- Desc: response fallo
[17-04-2023 00:00]-METODO: OnStop-- Desc: Ocurrio el problema:System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
   en MyNewService.Service1.ejecutarWS() en C:\Users\leona\source\repos\MyNewService\MyNewService\MyNewService .cs:línea 104
```

Comment: Your title mentions an error but I don’t see anything about that in the question. What error do you get?

Comment: The stuartd problem is that it doesn't query the information in the URL with the **RestClient** connection and I can't verify with screen prints so I print what happens in a Txt file.
As such there is no error but I try to print it to a file but I can't do it either because of some part of the code that doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Maybe the service does not have permission to write to `C:\\Users\\leona\\OneDrive\\Documents\\txt\\Test.txt`

Comment: ultado de traducción
Hello, Stuartd, I already modified the code and changed the place to another and it already writes to the file, but now the following message appears:

-METHOD: OnStop-- Desc: Problem occurred:System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An exception occurred on the target of the invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Cannot load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the specified file.